# Converting to a stored procedure

Tags: html, sql-server-2005, autocomplete

I currently have a query string for the jQuery Autocomplete plug in but should be using a stored procedure instead. Can anyone help me convert? It seems to not be working when I do it.

Original ASHX

```
public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["Rollup2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            //cmd.CommandText = "select NUID from T_USER where " +
            //"NUID like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.CommandText = "select rtrim(NUID) NUID, rtrim(FNAME) FNAME, rtrim(LNAME) LNAME from T_USER where NUID like @SearchText + '%' OR FNAME like @SearchText + '%' OR LNAME like @SearchText + '%'"; 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(sdr["NUID"].ToString() + " ").Append(sdr["FNAME"].ToString() + " ").Append(sdr["LNAME"].ToString() + " ")
                        .Append(Environment.NewLine); 
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

New ASHX for stored procedure:

```
public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["Rollup2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            //cmd.CommandText = "select NUID from T_USER where " +
            //"NUID like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.CommandText = "SP_AUTOCOMPLETE"; 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchText", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters["@SearchText"].Value = prefixText;


            cmd.Connection = conn;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(sdr["NUID"].ToString() + " ").Append(sdr["FNAME"].ToString() + " ").Append(sdr["LNAME"].ToString() + " ")
                        .Append(Environment.NewLine); 
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
@SearchText VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT RTRIM(NUID) NUID, RTRIM(FNAME) FNAME, RTRIM(LNAME) LNAME 
    FROM T_USER 
    WHERE NUID like @SearchText + '%' OR FNAME like @SearchText + '%' OR LNAME like @SearchText + '%'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the SqlCommand 'CommandType' to 'CommandType.StoredProcedure'.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

I would also recommend using a prefix other than 'sp_'.  That is what Microsoft used for their system procedures and you might accidentally overwrite one you want to keep around. :)

This is how I generate parameters:

```
public static SqlParameter GetParameter(string parameterName, object value, SqlDbType type, int size)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        value = DBNull.Value;
    }

    if (size <= 0 && type == SqlDbType.VarChar)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case SqlDbType.VarChar:
                size = 8000;
                break;
            case SqlDbType.NVarChar:
                size = 4000;
                break;
        }
    }

    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(parameterName, type, size);
    parameter.Value = value;
    parameter.IsNullable = true;

    return parameter;
}
```

And I just do this.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(GetParameter("@SearchText", searchText, SqlDbType.VarChar));
```

Comment: Nice to know about the SP_  Just how I was taught.  I just add the code you provided before I call the Stored Procedure right?  Also, it doesnt seem to be liking the cmd.executeReader() line

Comment: Yeah, put it up where you assign 'CommandText' and if you give me the error from cmd.ExecuteReader I can help.  It looks like you are adding your '@SearchText' parameter twice.

Comment: You are correct!
"Procedure or function SP_AUTOCOMPLETE has too many arguments specified."

Comment: Is cmd.ExecuteReader correct though? Sorry I am not really following.

Comment: I was elaborating on creating the parameters, you can execute a reader and loop through the results or use an SqlDataAdaper with its 'Fill' method to receive a set of DataTables and use those, whatever suits your needs.